# how to add servlet authorization using annotation

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to create an authorization mechanism which will run a servlet conditionally after checking request parameters. This authorization code should run before the servlet and should have a handle to the servlet object itself. That handle to the servlet object can be used to check if authorization annotation is defined or not. I explored filters for this, but filters don't have access to the servlet instance. What is the easiest way to get this interceptor like functionality?

Comment: Use a established web application framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat, you can create a LoggingFilter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get AOP-like behavior, is to use an AOP framework, like Guice or AspectJ. This will also work regardless of Java EE container.

THere is an example of this on the [Guice website](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP).

Answer (score 0):

For a real application you should use frameworks like [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) more simple on a first approach or [SpringSecurity](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) more powerful. I tried both and ended with last.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I tried one thing and it worked for me.I added below code in the super class :

```
    Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
    Method annotatedMethod = null;
    Annotation[] annotations = null;
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals("doGet") || method.getName().equals("doPost")) {
            annotations = method.getAnnotations();
            annotatedMethod = method;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note : DoPost method is annotation protected.